# htaccess block visitors from a certain search engine

Tags: .htaccess

Recently my website has been getting a lot of suspicious visits from weird countries like Congo, Saudia Arabia, Pakistan, India, Vietnam, Brazil. My website caters only to people in one city in USA, there is no reason why anyone from other cities or countries should be visiting it. They come from weird search engines. So for example instead of coming from google.com or yahoo.com they come from sexygirlsearch.info
I am getting hundreds of these per day. 
Every day, the search engine changes. but it is consistent throughout the day. For example yesterday it was all from alosearch.info
today it's all from sexygirlsearch.info
I believe these are human visitors because one of them actually filled out a contact form that has a human test.

so what's the solution to this? I have been doing a lot of reading and it appears that there is no reliable way to block countries.

can I block specific search engines? How can I block anyone coming from sexygirlsearch.info

Comment: sexygirlsearch.info sounds like [referrer spam.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spam) Google `htaccess block referer`, there's even an automated generator

Comment: Hello, actually, it is not referrer spam (I am aware of the old semalt referrer spam) this one, they actually come from that search engine. They type a relevant keyword in that search engine (I can see the keyword) and arrive to my site. I just need to block that entire search engine.

Comment: Fair enough! Google should get you started in either case though, see above.

Answer (score 0):

You can block specific HTTP referers in .htaccess. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} sexygirlssearch\.info [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} alosearch\.info [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} anotheronetoblock\.com
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

If the `HTTP_REFERER` *contains* either `sexygirlssearch.info`, `alosearch.info` or `anotheronetoblock.com` anywhere in the string then your default 403 Forbidden will be served.

Note that the last condition does not use the `OR` flag.

This should go at the top of your .htaccess file.